# Java - methods and final variables

Tags: java

Building a java program that helps the user practice their addition. Using the addition method, I added in my code as you can see below. It was giving me boolean errors. Also, it will run after the user enters its name and after that it gives errors.

> ***UPDATED***

**Error Command Prompt:**

```
CAI.java:46: error: missing return statement
    }
    ^
1 error
```

**CAI.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class CAI
{
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    static int addition;

    //main method
    public static void main(String[] arguments)
    {
        //declare variables
        String name;
        int addition;
        int subtraction;
        int multiplication;
        boolean = true;

        //welcome the user
        System.out.println("Welcome to Computer Assisted Instruction");

        //get the user's name
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        name = input.next();

        System.out.printf("Hi %s. Let's practice addition!", name);
    }   


    private static boolean addition()
    {
        //generate double digit numbers positive and negative
        int number = 0;
        //Addition
        System.out.printf("What is %d + %d? ", number);
        addition = input.nextInt();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** you have to initialize your variable :

```
int number = 0;
```

**Second** you can't use `System.out.println` like this you have to use `System.out.printf` instead for the int you have to use :

```
System.out.printf("What is %d + %d? ", number);
```

and for the String you have to use :

```
System.out.printf("Hi %s. Let's practice addition!", name);
```

**Third** your method should return an `boolean`, `return true : false;`.

**Forth** you can't initilize a variable exist in another method, instead you can put it in your class like an attribute like this :

```
public class MainM {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    static int addition;//<-----------------------

    //main method
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
```

**Fifth** you should not read an int with `next()`, you have to use `nextInt()`

Comment: `CAI.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
                addition = input.next();
                ^
  symbol:   variable addition
  location: class CAI
1 error`

Comment: `CAI.java:46: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
1 error`

Comment: i can't see your code, you can edit your question and post what you tried to do @TevelZaki

Comment: @TevelZaki remove `private static boolean addition() {` and replace it with `private static void addition() {` you don't need to return any boolean another thing also you don't need to use `boolean = true;`

Comment: This should be another question @TevelZaki

Answer (score 2):

```
 System.out.printf("Hi %d. Let's practice addition!", name);
```

here name is string not integer. use %s

```
     System.out.printf("Hi %s. Let's practice addition!", name);
```

Comment: you are welcome.. you can upvote/accept the answer you find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

%d is used for numeric values. However name is a `String` so use %s instead

Answer (score 0):

Your System.out.printf outputing the welcome message should have %s instead of %d, %d are for integers parameters, not strings.